# Meteor: Verifying user's twitter account, without logging in

Tags: meteor, twitter, oauth

Meteor can let a user authenticate that she controls a Twitter account [without logging in](https://www.meteor.com/accounts):

> **Standalone OAuth client use**
>
> If you just want to authenticate to an Oauth service like Twitter,
>   Facebook, or Google without using Accounts – that is, if you don't
>   want to log the user in, you just want an OAuth token – you can use
>   the underlying service packages such as twitter, facebook, and google
>   directly.

But, I haven't been able to find any information on how to do this in the documentations. I tried reading the packages for [twitter](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/twitter) and oauth, but it seems you have to change the code to make a call to Twitter without creating an account.

There are some solutions to a similar problem, like using `Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user)`, where you can hinder external services from making an account on your app. But, I want to let some twitter accounts create a normal account, and others to not be able to create one at all.

I tried adding a custom object to `Twitter.requestCredential(options, callback)` and to `Meteor.loginWithTwitter(options, callback)`, but neither worked.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem of letting users verify their twitter accounts without creating an account (and without completely stopping people from creating an account with twitter)?